# Convert number to Stars

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, rating

I've created this shortcode that converts a number to a star rating. At the moment, the shortcode works but not fully :

```
function Shortcode() {

$starNumber = get_field('note_independant');

for($x=1;$x<=$starNumber;$x++) {
    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
if (strpos($starNumber,',')) {
    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    $x++;
}
while ($x<=5) {
    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    $x++;
}

return $output;

 }

add_shortcode('helloworld', 'Shortcode');
```

Let say my field value note_independant = 3.

The shortcode output is ★★★ instead of ★★★☆☆.

I have also an issue when using a number with decimal like 3.5. The shortcode won't output half stars...

Comment: Your code has strpos on `,` not `.` so 3.5 won't work in your code but 3,5 will. Except 3,5 is not valid as a number in PHP.

Comment: I can't see any problems with the code except the `.` / `,` issue. https://3v4l.org/DCQoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem may depend on font Awesome version you use

in FA 5.5 use `fa fa-star-half-alt` for half star and `far fa-star` for blank star

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrap">
  <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  <i class="fa fa-star-half-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

and don't forget to replace comma `,` with dot `.` in `if (strpos($starNumber,',')) {`

Answer (score 1):

1. First remove `aria-hidden="true"` to display all blank and half star. Read more about [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)
2. Replace `','` to `'.'` to get work with decimal

   ```
     if (strpos($starNumber,'.')) {
   ```

Otherwise your code is working well : [Check Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58064d55cb288935f6578249a7c7362e0d945665)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use above solutions or WordPress star rating function instead.

Learn more about `wp_star_rating` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_star_rating/)